# CakePHP 3: How to check if file or image exists

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am just trying to check if an image exists or not, I can do it by using PHP. For example:-

```
$file = WWW_ROOT .'uploads' . DS . 'employee' . DS .'_'.check.jpg;

$file_exists = file_exists($file);
```

It's working fine for me. But I have tried also tried using `elementExists` like this:-

```
if($this->elementExists("../".$employees->front_image))
{
   echo $this->Html->image("../".$employees->front_image); // image output fine without condition.
}

// Here $employees->front_image = uploads/employee/employeename.jpg
```

This check is not working. How can I do this in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP is written in PHP, so if you already have a simple solution like `file_exists()` use that. So you can write something like this:-

```
if (file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $employees->front_image)):
   echo $this->Html->image('../' . $employees->front_image);
endif;
```

[`elementExists()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.View.html#_elementExists) is intended for checking that a View element exists, not if files exist in the webroot, so should not be used like you are trying. It does do a `file_exists()` check, but this scans all available View element paths only.

Comment: I am able to solve it by file_exists(). My question has there any method in cakephp to do this same thing ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. What you are attempting to do is a really simple check and any alternative methods provided by CakePHP would likely be overkill anyway as you would simply be calling a wrapper function that is going to call `file_exists()` in the end. If you look at the code for `elementExists()` you'll see that Cake uses `file_exists()` itself for checking a file exists. You presumably know exactly which directory your image file will exist in if it is present, so the best solution (and best for performance) will be to directly call `file_exists()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works in Cake 3 (you should do this in `afterFind` method IMO):

```
// Create a new file with 0644 permissions
$file = new File('/path/to/file.php', true, 0644);

if ($file->exists()) {
    //do something
}

$file->close();
```

Your way is checking whether view element exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Q: **How to check if image exists on remote url or not?**
Explanation:

- $rfile will take url
- $check will open the file with read rights
- If file exists then it will print "File exists" else "Doesn't exists".

code:

```
<?php
  // Remote file url
  $rFile = 'https://www.example.com/files/test.pdf';

  // Open the file
  $check = @fopen($rFile, 'r');

  // Check if the file exists
  if(!$check){
    echo 'File does not exist';
  }else{
    echo 'File exists';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).